# Search query in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to search in MySQL database by giving a keyword. At present i am doing like this

```
select keys from keysdata where model like 'keytype1%'
```

As per my query the output is

```
keytype1
keytype10
keytype11
keytype12
.
.
.
```

But I need a query such that if i type `keytype1` the output should be like

```
keytype1
keytype10
keytype11
keytype12
keytype01
keytype0011
keytype0012
.
.
.
```

Comment: Perhaps this helps: `select keys from keysdata where model like 'keytype%' and model like '%1%'`

Comment: @MaksimTikhonov Hi, this will work. but in my case user will search for the keys, pins and map with other keys/pins. I cannot ask himto simply search 1

Comment: @junglee So you should to make dynamic query

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [regular expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) here.

something like below:

```
 select keys from keysdata where (model REGEXP '^keytype[0-9]*')
```

For testing you can check your inputs against regex [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html)

Comment: hi gunjan mehta, i have tried this query. result is always all keytypes.